# Use of more and as many as in different place

Tags: word-usage, meaning, difference, phrase-usage

I wrote four sentence with “more” and “as much as” used in different places in sentences. Is there a difference among sentences in meaning ? It really confuses me.

> 1. There are ten times **more** bacterial cells than human cells in human body.

> 2. There are bacterial cells ten times **more** than human cells in human body.

> 3. There are ten times **as many** bacterial cells **as** human cells in human body.

> 4. There are bacterial cells ten times **as many as** human cells in human body.

Answer (score 1):

1) A grammatically correct English sentence indicating that the number of bacterial cells in the human body is equal to ten times (10x) the number of "human cells" in the human body (except there should be a "the" between "in" and "human") at the end.

2) An almost grammatically correct English sentence: if there was some quality that bacterial cells had ten times as much as, you could phrase a sentence correctly this way, e.g. There are bacterial cells ten times more *virulent* than human cells in *the* human body.

3) A grammatically correct English sentence (with one misspelled word) indicating that the number of bacterial cells in the human body is equal to ten times (10x) the number of "human cells" in the human body (except there should be a "the" between "in" and "human") at the end, despite omitting two words that, when added, still leave the sentence correct: There are ten times as many bacterial cells as *there are* human cells in *the* human body.

4) This one would need some work before it would be correct.

Comment: 2) There are bacterial cells that are ten times more than human cells .4)There are bacterial cells that are ten times as many as human cells in human body . Would it be correct if i say second and fourth sentences in this way? Because all translating engines give same meaning .

Comment: They are both technically almost correct in terms of English, but they're not saying what you want them to. Some people contend that saying "there are" when trying to express the existence of something is inelegant. Your best bet may be to say, "Bacterial cells can number up to <X number> in the human body, more than ten times the number of human cells. "

Answer (score 0):

1) Is fine, but the other 3 are not grammatically correct.
Slightly better would be *There are ten times more bacterial cells in the human body than human ones*
"*as much as*" does not work the way you have tried to use it. The closest would be *There are ten times as **many** bacterial cells as human cells in the human body.*
or, with a slightly different meaning where "*as much as*" could be replaces by *"up to*", setting an upper limit
*There are as much as ten times more bacterial cells in the human body as human ones.*